# Magento 2 REST API how to create an order on behalf of customer with Admin or integration token

Tags: rest, magento, token, orders

In our integration with Magento we need to create an order for a customer (not a guest) **without** the customer token. We're hoping that it is possible using Admin or Integration token.
Every thing works fine up to the point the order needs to be created by posting the payment information.
We only see APIs to do it with customer token (/carts/mine/payment-information) or for guest customer (/guest-carts/{cartId}/payment-information).

Does this means it is not possible to create an order on behalf of a customer using an **Admin or Integration** token ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To apply a payment method, you should be able to use the `carts/{cartId}/selected-payment-method` API. Note that the `cartId` is the actual int id and not the masked id.

Example `PUT` payload for `{{magentoProtocol}}://{{magentoDomain}}/rest/default/V1/carts/:cartId/selected-payment-method`

```
{
    "method": {
        "method": "stripe_payments",
        "additional_data": {
            "cc_stripejs_token": "{{stripePaymentToken}}",
            "cc_save": false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jessica! And sorry for replying only now.
I could successfully set the payment method and get an id in the response. And I was expecting to see the order using the following endpoint:
GET rest/default/V1/orders/orderId
but the response I get is:
{"message":"The entity that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the entity and try again."}

It looks like setting the payment method is not creating the order. Also I have no idea what is the id returned by the endpoint to set the payment method.
Any idea about how to create an order or what could have gone wrong ?
Thank you again!

Comment: When you set the payment method with the rest endpoint and receive an integer response, that integer is the entity id for the payment record. To place the order, you need to then call `rest/default/V1/carts/:cartId/order` with `PUT` and the id for the cart.

If the order is placed successfully, you'll receive the entity id for the order. You can then use that with `{{magento_base_url}}/rest/default/V1/orders/:id` to get the order details.

Comment: Again thank you very much Jessica! It just worked like you described. You're the best! ;)